# My BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() is not working properly in Lollipop API21

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth

Do i need to use BluetoothLeScanner class for scanning the BLE devices for Lollipop?

Problem with BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() in Lollipop:- Central device is unable to search for advertisement packets sent by peripheral in few BLE scanning time period. Though it is finding advertisement in some scanning intervals, and performing task (My app objective). But i want it to find advertisement in every time interval. I used time interval upto 10 second.

Is there any lollipop compatibility issue? I read that use of startLeScan() in lollipop is deprecated but we can use it though and it should work fine. Where i am wrong? Any Help?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question, Praveen? I realized that BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() finds less Beacons and after a while I have to reset the device to make sure it finds the beacons again. I wonder if this something similar to you observe.

Comment: Yeah, i have found solution, Please find it in answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was actually with Nexus 7 device (also with nexus 4) which I was using for development. Later I tried my code with nexus 5 and there is no such issue.

**Reason:**
On Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 the callback is invoked either when a new device has been found or when the sensor is non-connectable. In the later case you get RSSI updates constantly.

Advertising of the connectable device is more complicated than the non-connectable.
It requires 2 more packets: scan request and scan response. The phone must request more advertising data from the device. Thanks to that the adv data may be bigger than 31 bytes which are allowed in a single packet (for non-connectable devices).

Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 send the Scan request only once per device. Neither of them calls onLeScan callback if adv packet comes after it has been scanned.

In case of non-connectable devices the callback is being invoked each time the adv packet is received.
As I remember Nexus 5 sends Scan request multiple times for the same device, but I'm not sure.

It is very disturbing, that it works differently on some devices and the correct behaviour is not specified. The best solution would be to add a parameter to startLeScan(boolean showDevicesMultipleTimes) or standarize it to Nexus 5 behaviour.

**Link for this android issue:**

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=65863

**My suggested solution for Nexus 7 and Nexus 4:**
I switched my beacon into non-connectible mode and my code is working fine on all devices.